# why isn't the counting principle giving the right answer?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

Note : This is not homework, it is self-study.

> An employer interviews eight people for four openings in the company. Three of the eight people are women. If all eight are qualified, in how many ways could the employer fill the four positions if 
>   a)the selection is random
>   and
>   b)exactly two are women?

Part a) is already taken care of, now for part b). My reasoning goes like this:

There must be $2$ women chosen, so imagine that for the first position we choose a woman. There's $3$ ways to choose. For the second position we choose another woman, there's $2$ ways to choose. For the third position we choose a man, there's $5$ ways to choose. For the fourth position we choose another man, there's $4$ ways to choose. Then we multiply: $3\cdot2\cdot5\cdot4=120$. 
But the answer in the book is $30$.

Comment: If A and B are two of the women, then choosing A first then B is no different from choosing B first then A, so you must divide your result by 2.  Similarly for the men.

Comment: You probably wrote $\binom{8}{4}$ pretty automatically for a). So there you took it for granted that order does not matter.  Why then all of a sudden talk about a first position and a second?

Answer (score 6):

You can't simply multiply like that to get the correct number of combinations. What you are doing gives you the number of *permutations*, but as in this case order does not matter, that is incorrect.

Consider selecting $2$ women from a group of $3$ women. Your logic suggests there are six different possible combinations, which is clearly incorrect as there are $3$ combinations (as order does not matter). There are however, six permutations.

Once you've established the difference between the two and notice you require a combination for this question, your result is 
given by 
$$
{3 \choose 2} \cdot {5 \choose 2} = 30
$$

Comment: While this is apparently what the author of the book had in mind, it’s based on what I consider a very odd interpretation of the question: it assumes that the positions are interchangeable. As I read the question, the correct answer ought to be $\binom32\binom52\cdot4!$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I agree, I honestly had the same thought and considered making that correction, thanks for the answer. That's the one thing with lots of problems of this nature (_I found at least, some time ago_), the degree left open for interpretation leaves something to be desired sometimes.

Comment: I agree: some authors are pretty careless with the wording of their problems in this area.

Comment: Did anybody ever state the book’s answer for the first part of the question?  I don’t see it.  I see the suggestion/implication that it is $8 \choose 4$.  Well, if the four positions are distinct, then the answer to part (a) is $8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5$ = $\frac{8!}{4!}$ = ${8 \choose 4} \cdot 4!$.  If the OP answered $8 \choose 4$ for part (a), then he should have proceeded naturally to ${3 \choose 2} \cdot {5 \choose 2}$ for part (b).

Comment: the book's answer for a) is 70, which I got right, it seemed obvious to me that it was a combination problem. I guess I don't understand very well how to apply the counting principle.

Answer (score 4):

The book’s answer assumes that the positions are indistinguishable, i.e., that the question is simply asking how many ways there are to choose $2$ women and $2$ men; **Donkey Kong**’s answer explains the reasoning behind the resulting calculation.

Your calculation assumes that the positions *are* distinguishable: that putting persons $A,B,C$, and $D$ in positions $1,2,3$, and $4$, respectively, is different from putting person $A$ in position $2$, person $B$ in position $1$, and persons $C$ and $D$ in positions $3$ and $4$, respectively. That is also how I would read the question. However, in that case your answer is still not right, though it’s closer than the one in the book. The problem is that your calculation doesn’t account for the assignments in which the women do *not* occupy the first two positions. To get the correct result using your interpretation, start with the calculation of $30$ ways to choose $2$ men and $2$ women. Then note that you can assign the $4$ chosen applicants to the $4$ positions in $4!$ different ways, for a total of $30\cdot4!=720$ different ways to fill the positions.

Answer (score 1):

We need to choose $2$ women from the available $3$ and then choose $2$ men from the available $5$. This gives us $${3 \choose 2}\cdot {5 \choose 2} = 3 \cdot 10 = 30.$$